# React Native Flatlist Load More On Scroll (Fetch API)

Tags: php, react-native

loading more doesn't work correctly,and what I want when reloading the page, the data that appears in the flatlist should be limited, for example when reloading the page the data must appear 10 first, then when scroll down and reappear 10 more additional data.. I don't know where it went wrong. Please help me .I don't know how to make it load more and have tried many existing scripts and the result is still the same, help me in solving this problem

```
     function getBarang(namex){
    
    setLoading(true);
    dataStorageNews == ''
      ? setLoading(false)
      : fetch('https://example/api_doc/proses_api.php', {
          method: 'POST',   
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            aksi: 'load_potensi_all_filter',
            uru_id_desa: dataStorageNews[0].uru_id_desa,
            nama_potensi: namex,
            filter: selected
          }),
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
         
            setDataList(prevData => [...prevData,...responseJson.result]);
            setLoading(false);

//view
 <FlatList
          //keyExtractor={item => item.index_potensi}
          data={DataList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={10}
          onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          ListFooterComponent={() =>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loadMoreButton} onPress={handleLoadMore}>
            <Text style={styles.loadMoreButtonText}>
              {loading ? 'Loading...': 'Load More..'}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          }
```

Comment: hello can you please provide more detail

which api call when click on more button

Comment: in fact, when I press the load more button, all the data appears and is not limited...

Comment: and what I want when reloading the page, the data that appears in the flatlist should be limited, for example when reloading the page the data must appear 10 first, then when scroll down and reappear 10 more additional data...and my script above doesn't work as I want

Comment: I apologize if my answer is incomplete and my English is bad bro

Comment: ok you need to add pagination

Comment: @MahammadMomin how to make limit parameters in this code
`fetch('https://example/api_doc/proses_api.php', {
          method: 'POST',   
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            aksi: 'load_potensi_all_filter',
            uru_id_desa: dataStorageNews[0].uru_id_desa,
            nama_potensi: namex,
            filter: selected
          }),
        })`

Comment: I've tried but it still doesn't work like this `'https://example/api_doc/proses_api.php?offset=10&limit=5'`

Comment: if backend side have limit param in api then it's work other wise you need to call api at first time and get all data and then tou apply custom pagination in flatlist :)